# Sessions Management

Tags: php, session

I have problem with session. I create a different Session file with name Session.php & want to include this file in each page of website to manage session. can it work? suggest me please I am a fresher and working first time woth session .

my session.php file is as follow

```
<?php  include("lib/config.php"); 
function start_session() { 
$_SESSION['userid']=$rows[0]; 
$_SESSION['first_name']=$rows[2]; 
$_SESSION['last_name']=$rows[3]; 
$_SESSION['user_email']=$rows[4]; 
$_SESSION['user_password']=$rows[5]; 
$_SESSION['user_gen']=$rows[6]; 
$_SESSION['user_contact']=$rows[7]; 
$_SESSION['picture']="profile/".$rows_pic[0]; 
$user_id=$_SESSION['userid']; 
$fnam=$_SESSION['first_name']; 
$lnam=$_SESSION['last_name']; 
$email=$_SESSION['user_email']; 
$pic_ed=$_SESSION['picture']; 
} 

function destroy() {   
session_destroy(); 
} 

?>
```

Comment: can it? did it? what happened when you tried it?

Comment: where to follow your session file ?

Comment: sorry but your code is invisible to me.

Comment: you have 3 variables with the same value, seems pointless

Answer (score 0):

You need to include session_start() at the top of your file then your function will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have used $rows in function, what is that variable?

2) yes, you can include that file in all pages, but better you create session.php under lib folder and include that file in lib/config.php. So you just need to include config.php in all pages.

3) You need session_start() at very top most code of your php file.

Answer (score -1):

What is the use of creating session.php file?

You can access session like that:

@session_start();

if you want to write new session than use like that $_SESSION['MySession'] = 'XYZ';

Accessing Session echo $_SESSION['MySession'];

You can access session $_SESSION['MySession'] on every page but you need to include @session_start() at the top of every php file.

Comment: firstly i was access session with "session_start();" and it was work properly but it also show a warning.  "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/fundumob/public_html/Login/functions.php:8) in /home/fundumob/public_html/Login/confirm.php on line 48

Comment: Please put @ before session_start().
Like @session_start()